# POST not working with no signs of error

Tags: php, forms, post, isset

haven't programmed PHP in a while but I
have to assemble something for a client really fast.
I've set up 2 forms with POST but when I go to the next file it's just blank space, for some reason POST isn't being registered but is set cause I'm not getting an error echo.
Hese's the forms:

```
<form action="Funkcije.php" method="post" name="AddFromDB">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Šifra Art" name="ArtNo">
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj">
        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="newItem">
            <form action="Funkcije.php" method="post" name="AddNew">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Šifra" name="Art">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ime Proizvoda" name="ImeProizvoda">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Dobavljač" name="Dobava">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Cijena" name="Cijena">
                <input type="submit" value="Dodaj">
            </form>
        </div>
```

And here's the 2nd file:

```
if(isset($_POST["AddFromDB"], $_POST["ArtNo"])){
    addExisting ($_POST["ArtNo"]);
} 
else if(isset($_POST["AddNew"], $_POST["Art"], $_POST["ImeProizvoda"], $_POST["Dobava"], $_POST["Cijena"])){
    newItem ($_POST["Art"] && $_POST["ImeProizvoda"] && $_POST["Dobava"] && $_POST["Cijena"]);
}
else if (!isset ($_POST)){
    echo "error";
}
```

So, by code I should be getting an error if POST is not set but I get nothing. Just a blank space.

Comment: You should verify what return in $_POST, use:

var_dump($_POST);

Enjoy your code!

Comment: Note:`isset($_POST["AddFromDB"])` and `isset($_POST["AddNew"])` will always be false as the `name` attribute of the form(s) is not posted.

Comment: If there's a blank space - check erros in error log

Comment: since `$_POST` is a superglobal, it is always set. You will want to change `else if (!isset ($_POST))` to either `else if (empty($_POST))` or `else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')`

Comment: now, check the answer, you must be give a name to the submit button to check in PHP page which form is submitted... thank you..

Comment: @KalpeshRajai `you must be give a name to the submit button to check in PHP page which form is submitted.` This is not entirely correct. You don't have to give a submit button a name. You can check any other form element, including adding a hidden element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, you must be give a name to the submit button to check which form is POST like this...

```
<form  method="post" name="AddFromDB">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Šifra Art" name="ArtNo">
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" name="form1">
        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="newItem">
            <form  method="post" name="AddNew">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Šifra" name="Art">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ime Proizvoda" name="ImeProizvoda">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Dobavljač" name="Dobava">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Cijena" name="Cijena">
                <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" name="form2">
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["form1"], $_POST["ArtNo"])){
    echo "1";
} 
else if(isset($_POST["form2"], $_POST["Art"], $_POST["ImeProizvoda"], $_POST["Dobava"], $_POST["Cijena"])){
    echo "2";
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

now, this work fine..

thank you.. enjoy coding...

Comment: The OP could just as easily change it to `<input type="submit" value="Dodaj" name="AddFromDB">`|`<input type="submit" value="Dodaj" name="AddNew">` and not have to change the `$_POST['AddFromDB']`|`$_POST['AddNew']` in their php code.